# Constants class vs global constants

Tags: php, constants

I'm working on a project where all the global constants have been defined in a class called Constants, for example

```
class Constants
{

  const MIN_VALUE = 0.0;
  const MAX_VALUE = 1.0;

  public static function getMinValue()
  {
    return self::MIN_VALUE;
  }

  public static function getMaxValue()
  {
    return self::MAX_VALUE;
  }

  public static function getValueDependingOnURL()
  {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'something')
    {
      return self::MIN_VALUE;
    }
    else
    {
      return self::MAX_VALUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Then throughout the code something like `Constants::getMaxValue()` is used to get the value of a constant.  This seems a very strange approach why wouldn't you just use the `define` function in the outermost scope?  I know `define()` can be quite slow but surely having to call a class property is not the most efficient way either?

EDIT: Also some of the functions have conditions in them hence why functions are called

Comment: Why have the static methods? Constants::MIN_VALUE will work exactly the same.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why do 2 people close vote this "opinion based" ? There are clear advantages and disadvantages over configuration containers and global defined constants. This has nothing to do with opinion. Seems the question viewers are on the same software design expierence level as OP himself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearify the question: **What is the advantage of a configuration container over globally `define()`ed configuration contstants?**

The advantages are all the advantages that OOP offers: **Data Abstraction and Encapsulation**, **Inheritance**, **Polymorphism** and **better design pattern integration**.

The readers of this thread seem a little confused and focus on your class rather than the main question. To also clearify this, let me give you an example:

```
class Configuration
{
    protected $someValue;
}

class ConfigurationDev extends Configuration
{
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://devel.yoursite.com/';
}

class ConfigurationLive extends Configuration
{
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://www.yoursite.com/';
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$config   = new ConfigurationDev;
$tracking = new Tracking($config);
...
```

class Tracking:

```
class Tracking
{
    public function __construct(\Configuration $config) {
        if ($config instanceof \ConfigurationLive) {
            // We are in live environment, do track
        } else {
            // Debug Notice: We are NOT in live environment, do NOT track
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation of the scenario:**

Imagine you want to track users, but only on the live system, not on your development system. The Tracking class expects a live configuration but aborts (without impact) if its not the live config.

Your class with `const` is not the best, because `const` implies you do not want to change the variables. Do not use the variable for values that may change. You shouldn't use static stuff either because it mostly conflicts with dependency injection. Pass real objects!

Your function `public static function getValueDependingOnURL()` should be placed in a Helper class, not in a Constant/Configuration container either.

```
class Helper
{
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(\Configuration $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getValueByUrl($url) {
        if ($url == 'something') {
            return $config->getMinValue();
        } else {
            return $config->getMaxValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can have different sets of configuration which the helper class relies on:

```
$config = new ConfigurationLive;
$helper = new Helper($config);
$value  = $helper->getValueByUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

---

There is a lot of best practice design pattern stuff, code style and OOP in my examples, learn about those and you will gain a much higher level of software engineering than the readers of your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could do also the short way of getting constants like `Constants::MIN_VALUE`. Try this yourself.

Comment: Yeah I could.  But some of the functions perform conditions so the function needs to be called

Comment: @Pattle: "Perform **conditions**"? To return the value of a **constant**?

Comment: Alright I see. But I think declaring a variable global is not good as it breaks the principles of good software engineering. It may also clutter your code if global variables are not stored in one file.

Comment: The question is not how to improve the code, the question is what is the advantage of a container class compared to `define`

Comment: Then what he did was correct. @Pattle maintained his validations in the methods of the class that greatly promotes code reusability.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about advantages of class constants vs. constants defined in the global scope, I would say that a class constant can be a cleaner approach because of its limited scope. Also it makes sense to have a `MAX_VALUE` constant defined in a class that uses it, not somewhere else.

But that does not seem to apply in your case, because your `Constants` class appears to act like a container for some random constants. `MIN_VALUE` of what?